# free the memory in C

Tags: c, free

The result of **code 1** is still `10` after you free pointer `p` and `p` is not `NULL`.
the inputs of **code 2** are `5` (length) and `1 2 3 4 5` for the value of each node, but the output is nothing under the condition that all the following nodes are not `NULL`.

My question is that based on the logic of **code 1**, shouldn't all the values of nodes be printed because they are not `NULL`?

Can anyone explain to me? Thank you so much!

**code 1**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
     int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
     *p = 10;
     free(p);
     if (p != NULL) {
         printf("%d\n", *p);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

**code 2**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    struct Node *next;
    int value;
} Node, *list;

list create_Node() {
    list head = (list)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (!head)
        exit(-1);
    list tail = head;
    int len;
    int val;
    printf("Please enter the length of the list:\n ");
    scanf("%d", &len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        list new = (list)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if (!new)
            exit(-1);
        printf("Please enter the value of the node:\n ");
        scanf(" %d", &val);
        new->value = val;
        tail->next = new;
        tail = new;
    }
    return head;
}

int delete_List(list l) {
    if (l == NULL) {
        printf("List is empty!");
        exit(-1);
    }
    list temp;
    while (l) {
        temp = l->next;
        free(l);
        l = temp;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    Node *n = create_Node();
    n = n->next;
    delete_List(n);
    while (n->next != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", n->value);
        n = n->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don’t ever handle `next` assignments properly (it’s never set to NULL anywhere etc) so the code has undefined behavior.

Comment: so how should I handle next assignment properly?? Thank you !

Comment: Set it to NULL on allocation, set it to NULL when you remove items from the linked list. Otherwise you have dangling pointers which cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

having

> ```
> int main(){
>   int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
>   *p = 10;
>   free(p);
>   if(p!=NULL)
>   {
>     printf("%d\n",*p);
>   }
>   return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> My question is that based on the logic of code 1, shouldn't all the values of nodes be printed because they are not NULL??

Except in the case there are no more memory the *malloc* will works and return a non null value, after the *free* the value of *p* is unchanged and still non null so the code try to read in the free memory and this is an undefined behavior

There are better way to ( try to) print a random value :-)

in code 2 this is the same, you access to free memory, both in the test of the *while* and in the *printf* and the value to assign *n*

Comment: But in code 2 there is noting in result while the value of p is printed after p was freed in code 1. Why??

Comment: @Liu in code2 like in code1 the behavior is **undefined**, int code2 the value of `n->next` and `n->value` are **undefined**

Comment: @Liu you have to print before to free, so in code1 replace `free(p);     if (p != NULL) { printf("%d\n", *p); }` by `printf("%d\n", *p); feee(p);` and in code2 move the call of _delete_List(n);_ in main after the _while_. What do you not understand ?

Comment: @Liu in that case choose one of the two answers to mark the question closed

Comment: i have another question, if you pass a pointer to a function, like delete_List(list l) in code 2,  you can change the value of the pointer but you can't change the address  of it in function delete_List, then in main method, why the list was successfully freed??

Comment: @Liu I was the first to post the right answer but I still do not have any up, so I propose you to follow the votes and ask the other guy. I will probably delete that wasted answer ...

Comment: I am really sorry, I know you answered many of my questions, but for a newbie here , my reputation is not enough to thumb up your answer. I tried many times.  Your answers helped quite a lot!!

Comment: @Liu you never like the answers ? you asked 4 questions and 3 of them receives answer(s) but you have not accepted any answer. All the answer are wrong ?

Comment: i need u guys answers so badly!!! Especially yours. I trie to like but I am newbie i don't have enough reputation to like ur answer and I am not too familiar with stack overflow. Is it takes some time .

Comment: @Liu it is easy to see O.P even with for instance reputation 3 accepted answer ! What are you speaking about ?

Comment: O.P ?? don't know what it is.  And I a not familiar with stackover flow.  Sorry

Answer (score 2):

> ...based on the logic of code 1...

Code 1 accesses freed memory (a so-called *dangling pointer*), which is **undefined behavior**. Anything can happen, including, but not limited to, your program crashing, the last value being returned (= the behavior you observed) or the program doing something completely unexpected.

Thus, you cannot infer *anything* from "the logic of code 1".

Comment: So how should I solve the undefined behavior issue??
if (p != NULL) {
         p == NULL; printf("%d\n", *p);
     }

Comment: @Liu: By not accessing `p` after it has been freed, i.e., by moving `free(p)` 3 lines down in Code 1.